# Show/remove multiple markers on map by using geo query

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, geocoding

I have a button in my app that, when pressed, it has to open google maps and show inside in it some markers. Another button has to remove those markers when pressed. In more details, those markers have to be centered in the origins of geofences already setted.

I know that it's possible to make a query by using geo queries, (for example *"geo:0,0?q=my+street+address"*), but I can't figure out if it's possible to query more than one address (for example *"geo:0,0?q=my+street+address&mysecond+street+address&mythird+street+address"* and so on). If it is possible, is there any chances to show (or remove) those markers too?

Thank you all!

Comment: If you need full control over markers, probably [Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start) is the right option.